# Php checkdnsrr function returns incorrect result for blacklist search

Tags: php, laravel, dns, blacklist

I have a function that checking if IP in known blacklists and it returning incorrect data.

```
  $ip = '185.91.153.27';
  $host = 'zen.spamhaus.org';
  $reverse_ip = implode(".", array_reverse(explode(".", $ip)));
  if (checkdnsrr($reverse_ip . "." . $host . ".", "A")) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
```

It retruns true but in spamhaus website it shows that ip isn't in blacklist.
What's wrong with this method or does exists any other solutions?

Comment: Where is `$zone` defined? (and I think you have to many `.`'s)

Comment: It's the same host, typo. I forgot to change it, it's just for example.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using both the IP address and the hostname - the manual states that either can be used - but I expect not both.  Also - why do you reverse the IP address?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're looking specifically for `27.153.91.185.zen.spamhaus.org`, which no, does not resolve to an IP address. If it is for you, then your DNS cache needs to be cleared. The other alternative is that your ISP is using a DNS redirect for unknown IPs/Domains. I know that AT&T and/or Spectrum, for a few, are bad about that.

Comment: Yes in other examples shown that you need to reverse IP and . is preferable in the end. The main purpose is to check if this IP stored in "spamhaus" blacklist DB.

Comment: Try doing `nslookup 27.153.91.185.zen.spamhaus.org` on the command line of the system you're running the code on. If it returns an IP, run `whois` on that IP to see who it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks @aynber instead of `nslookup` i used `dig` and it resolved my problem.

Comment: @NativeNova you can probably mark the question as solved. Otherwise add an 'answer' and mark that answer as the solution.